# Calling subclass constructors from the base constructor in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, subclass, base-class

I'd like to call subclass constructors from the base constructor and have the created subclass object as a base class object.
The code looks like this.

```
class Text
{
    public string OriginalText;

    public Text() { }

    public Text(string text)
    {
        OriginalText = text;
        text = FormatText(text); // like text.ToUpper().Trim()

        if (Category1.Check(text))
            new Category1(text);
        else if (Category2.Check(text))
            new Category2(text);
        else if (Category3.Check(text))
            new Category3(text);
    }

}

class Category1 : Text
{
    public string Property1;
    public Category1(string text)
    {
        Property1 = text + "#1";
    }

    static public bool Check(string text)
    {
        return text == "category1";
    }
}

class Category2 : Text
{
    public string Property2;
    public Category2(string text)
    {
        Property2 = text + "(2)";
    }

    static public bool Check(string text)
    {
        return text == "category2";
    }
}

class Category3 : Text
{
    public string Property3;
    public Category3(string text)
    {
        Property3 = text + "%3";
    }

    static public bool Check(string text)
    {
        return text == "category3";
    }
}
```

However, `var t = new Text("category1")` was not an object of the subclass. I checked that by evaluating `t is Category1` which was `false`. I tried adding 
`return` in front of `new Category1(text)` but since a constructor returns a void type this approach failed. The following is the error message translated from Japanese.

```
An object statement can't be used after the keyword return since MainWindow.Text.Text(string)' returns void type
```

One way to work around this is defining a static method which returns a subclass object.

```
static public Text GetCategory(string text)
{
    text = FormatText(text);
    if (Category1.Check(text))
        return new Category1(text);
    else if (Category2.Check(text))
        return new Category2(text);
    else if (Category3.Check(text))
        return new Category3(text);
    return null;
}
```

However, this time, `OriginalText = text;` can't be used since this is a static method. I admit one can deal with this by adding the following code to every

single one of the contents of the `if` statements

```
string tmp1 = text;
text = FormatText(text);
var c1 = new Category1(text); 
c1.OriginalText = tmp1;
return c1;
```

or setting `OriginalText` in every subclass constructor.

But this would make the code lengthy, redundant and hard to read and maintain. I'd like to aggregate common processes in the same place, I mean, the base constructor.

Googling "call subclass constructor c#" gave me 2 articles, which weren't answers for me.

1. [Calling subclass constructor from static base class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673636/calling-subclass-constructor-from-static-base-class-method)
   This is irrelevant. It's about calling a static subclass method inherited from the base class.
2. [How to call subclass constructor only in inheritence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360746/how-to-call-subclass-constructor-only-in-inheritence)
   This is different. This one is about calling subclass constructors without calling the base class constructor.

How can I deal with this issue?

Comment: "I'd like to call subclass constructors from the base constructor and have the created subclass object as a base class object." There's no such thing as "a base class object". Only a single object is created, and its type is correct from the start. It looks like what you really want is a static factory method instead.

Comment: *"OriginalText = text; can't be used since this is a static method"* - Sure it can.  It's `public`.  Instead of using `return` and `new` on the same line, use separate lines of code.  Create your `new` object, set your value(s) on that object, then return that object.  You can't set that value on `this`, but that's not where you *want* to set it anyway.  You want to set it on the object instance being returned.

Answer (score 2):

In the code block you are talking about, you are creating a new instance, but it is never assigned to a variable and it can't be returned from a constructor either:

```
if (Category1.Check(text))
    new Category1(text); // <-- wrong!
```

A constructor is a method to initialize the newly created space in memory for the given type. You can't change the type from a constructor!

You want a factory pattern, lik you have given in your second example. That is your best and only option:

```
static public Text GetCategory(string text)
{
    text = FormatText(text);
    if (Category1.Check(text))
        return new Category1(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Patrick correctly explains, you want to use a Factory Pattern.
Regarding the `OriginalText`, you don't have to repeat this code. Simply create your factory method like this:

```
static public Text GetCategory(string text)
{
    var formattedText = FormatText(text);
    Text result = null;
    if (Category1.Check(formattedText))
        result = new Category1(formattedText);
    else if (Category2.Check(formattedText))
        result = new Category2(formattedText);
    else if (Category3.Check(formattedText))
        result = new Category3(formattedText);
    if(result != null)
        result.OriginalText = text;
    return result;
}
```